# Cual es la forma correcta de inicializar un propiedad en MVVM

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, mvvm

Tengo una pregunta, ¿es correcto inicializar una propiedad `full` en el `ViewModel` de la siguiente manera?

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<Driver> _drivers = new ObservableCollection<Driver>();
    public ObservableCollection<Driver> Drivers
    {
        get { return _drivers; }
        set { _drivers = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

}

¿Es correcto?, ¿es una mala práctica? o ¿se debe realizar de otra manera?. Mi pregunta surge ya que estaba tratando de llenar esa colección con un método que inicializaba el campo pero los cambios no se me reflejaban en el `XAML` que esta enlazado a la propiedad `Drivers`, Solo instanciando el campo `_drivers` de esta manera logre que funcionara.
Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No lo veo incorrecto, pero recomendaria inicializar en el constructor del `ViewModel`

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        _drivers = new ObservableCollection<Driver>();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Driver> _drivers = null;
    public ObservableCollection<Driver> Drivers
    {
        get { return _drivers; }
        set 
        { 
            _drivers = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Es exactamente lo mismo asignarla como en el ejemplo de la pregunta que hacerlo en el constructor. Y la asignación que estás haciendo con `null` es redundante, el default es `null`.

Comment: @gbellmann le asigno null porque al compilar .net suele marcarte un error indicando las variable no estan asignadas, por eso aunque sea redundante recomendaria definirle un valor

Answer (score 1):

**Cuidado**, al parecer estas implementando INotifyPropertyChanged, si te bindeas a una propiedad antes de instanciarla, y la instancías asi:

```
_drivers = new ObservableCollection<Driver>();
```

**No vas a llamar al Setter de la propiedad y por lo tanto, el XAML (GUI) no va a reaccionar ante el cambio.**

Es decir tienes:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource={Binding Drivers}> ... </DataGrid>
```

Y estas creando una instancia del campo privado _drivers, sin pasar por la propiedad observable Drivers, el XAML (GUI) no se va a dar cuenta del cambio

Crea la instancia usando la propiedad observable para "avisarle" al GUI que hay una nueva instancia:

```
Drivers = new ObservableCollection<Driver>();
```

Independientemente de esto y respondiendo a tu pregunta original, te recomiendo instanciar tus propiedades y variables en el constructor, o inclusive en un metodo separado por ejemplo "Inicializar()" y manda a llamar este metodo desde el constructor, asi **tienes mas control sobre donde estas creando tus intancias**, pero esto depende de las preferencias de cada quien

Inclusive puedes tener tus propiedades en una clase estatica y tenerlas de manera global accesibles a toda la aplicacion (parecido al patron "singleton")

Comment: pero cuando se inicaliza la instancia del viewmodel desde la view aun no realizo ninguna peticion a los `set` de las propiedades, por lo que asignar la propiedad o la variable privada tendria el mismo efecto. Ahora bien si haces esto una vez que este la view ya cargada ahi si cambia la situacion y debe asignarse la propiedad para que lance el PropertyChange y notifica el binding en el xaml.